# Connecting to database but I only get Default schemas not the ones I created on the original system. Any Ideas?

Tags: java, netbeans, derby

So I have a database which i want to transfer to another system. I copied the files installed java, derby, netbeans and have set the paths on the new system's environment variables. In netbeans although I am able to connect to the database, I only get the default Schemas and not the ones I have created, so my code doesn't work.

copied the files installed java, derby, netbeans and have set the paths on the new system's environment variables

I expect to get connected to the database not jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/ThessAlex68 [ on Default schema] but jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/ThessAlex68 [ me on ME]

where ME are my schemas i created.

Answer (score 0):

Your data is stored in a folder called `ThessAlex68`. If you don't copy the data, and if you specify `create=true` when you start your program, Derby will create a new empty database.

That is probably what has happened in your case.

The easiest and best way to copy your data to your new system is to:

1. Make a backup on the old system
2. Copy the backup to the new system
3. Restore the backup on the new system

Learn more about backing up and restoring your database here: http://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.15/adminguide/cadminhubbkup98797.html

Comment: Hey there Bryan,sorry for my late response and thank you for your answer, I am going to try what you suggested and will tell you the results.